# windows task scheduler: how trigger task then program has closed?

Tags: windows, batch-file, task, scheduler

I'm building a specific task.

I need to track when a program ends, make report and analyze it. So, I want to create a schedule for it.

For example, I have process called `testing.exe`, and I want to check for it's log after it finishes job. I have `analyze.bat` file. I just need something to run it, just after `testing.exe` finishes it's job and closes.

I can't change anything in program code, so I believe, that task scheduler is the only way.

Help me please

Comment: task scheduler does have "on an invent" as a trigger possibility, but if you can't mod your task, then you can't really add some code to trigger that event. probably your best bet is just a simple/stupid batch file: `testing.exe && analyze.bat` to chain the commands.

Comment: I can mod my task, i just can't add anything to the software.
Also testing.exe && analyze.bat doesn't fit me. Because the will be many different testing running.

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler is not even required for this! It can be done under just batch!

```
@echo off
set batdir=____________
:begin
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq testing.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "testing.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto start
goto begin
:start
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq testing.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "testing.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto start
start %batdir%\analyze.bat
```

Just replace _________ with the directory of analyze.bat and it should work. What it does is: it first waits for testing.exe to start. If it started or was already on, it switches and now waits for testing.exe to close. Once it closes, it starts analyze.bat which is exactly what you wanted without the need of Task Scheduler. Hope I helped!